# Some HTML elements are missing when crawling using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape some texts from HTML elements from a website. Mostly went fine but for some reasons Scrapy doesn't get all HTML elements as shown in browser inspect. The content is static as I tried disabling JavaScript but still have those missing elements show in my browser.
That website is structured similar to this:

```
<ul class="paragraph-title">...</ul>
<ul class="paragraph-title">
    <p>TEXT 1</p>
    <p class="list-item">TEXT 2</p>
    <p class="list-item">TEXT 3</p>
</ul>
<ul class="paragraph-title">
    <p>TEXT 4</p>
    <ol class="level-one"></ol>
    <ol class="level-two">
        <li class="level-two-item">TEXT 5</li>
        <li class="level-two-item">TEXT 6</li>
    </ol>
</ul>
<ul class="paragraph-title">...</ul>
```

This is my Scrapy Spider:

```
import scrapy
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "MySpider"
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']
def parse(self, response):
    entries = response.css('ul.paragraph-title')
    for entry in entries:
        yield {
            'text': entry.css('::text').getall()
        }
```

When I tried `entries[2].getall()` in `scrapy shell` and, I noticed scrapy failed to find ol and li tags in the third ul:

```
['<ul class="paragraph-title"><p>TEXT 4</p></ul>']
```

How do I get 'TEXT 5' and 'TEXT 6' from the li tags?

Comment: Huh, you've found a weird one here, replace `ol` with any other tag and your code works... very strange

Comment: @tomjn So is it possible that this is scrapy's bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lxml.html` directly (e.g. with `lxml.html.tostring(lxml.html.parse('foo.html'))`) to check how does it parse this HTML code. In this case it is

```
<ul class="paragraph-title">
    <p>TEXT 4</p>
    </ul><ol class="level-one"></ol>
    <ol class="level-two">
        <li class="level-two-item">TEXT 5</li>
        <li class="level-two-item">TEXT 6</li>
    </ol>
```

So it doesn't support nesting `ol` inside `ul`. I don't know if it's a bug or a deliberate decision.